# What snippet do I need to type to show my ACF field show up on my theme?

Tags: plugins, posts, custom-field, post-meta, advanced-custom-fields

I've been trying all kinds of things but I can't get it to work cuz my Theme single.php looks different that usual.

I made a field in ACF named Region and then enter for example USA which I need to show up in my post meta, like the edited screenshot below:
[image]

[image: example]

And ofc all works fine at the back-end but I can't figure out what to type and where to place it in my single.php to show up on the front-end.

This is what my single.php looks like:
[image]

Now I tried to copy their style like the ;title'=> etc, tried to paste the snippet from ACF but nothing is working which most likely is because I screwed up and it's probably easy for someone that has more exp with ACF but it's hard for me. I need to this on several other websites with different values so if someone get point me in the right direction I will use it a lot and would be very grateful.

Cheers!

Comment: Please don't post code snippets as images; [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/406990/edit) and insert the actual code into the editor. You can use the "code sample" button (`{}`) in the editor to format your code. Also, if this is a "how do I use ACF" question, you're likely to have more luck asking ACF's support team.

Comment: ACF has tons of documentation: the [opening tutorial in their documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/).

Comment: @deflime Please be kind.

Comment: @deflime I know but as this theme single.php is a bit weird, I haven't found a snippet that has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

You had to use this code

```
get_field( "region" );
```

this will get you the region value of current post

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.

I tried to put it below title and no result, I also tried to format it like they did, so under title:

'region' => get_field(),

but no luck. :(

Comment: can you try passing the post id like this get_field( "region", 123 ); in see if it works

Comment: Unfortunately did not work plus I don't need it on a single post ID ofc.

Comment: can you send the code where you trying to use ?

Comment: Its in the first post, the single.php

Comment: i just want to see your code that has the get_field("region") function